# "Robust" partitioning of matroid unions

Tags: co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

Let $M$ be a matroid. 
(Assume that $M$ is a graphic matroid if it helps.)
Let $M^2 = M \vee M$ be a union of $M$ by itself. 
See e.g. [this lecture note](https://theory.stanford.edu/~jvondrak/CS369P/lec11.pdf) for the definition of matroid union.

From the definition of matroid union, we have the following:
There is a fixed partitioning $P$ of all independent sets of $M^2$ such that
for any independent set $I$ of $M^2$, we have $P(I) = (I_1,I_2)$ where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are disjoint independent sets of $M$.

Is there a partition $P$ that also has the additional "robustness" property below?

> For any two independent sets $I$ and $I'$ where the size of symmetric difference $|I \triangle I'|$ is small, say at most 2, 
>   we have both $|I_1 \triangle I'_1|$ and $|I_2 \triangle I'_2|$ are small, say at most some constant.

Comment: If by $k$-fold sum you mean the direct sum of $k$ copies of $M$, then the property in the second paragraph isn't quite true: Each $I_i$ is an independent of the $i^\text{th}$ copy $M_i$ of $M$, and not of $M$ itself. That said, given an independent set $I$ of $M^k$ one still has the partition  $P(I) = (I_1, \dots, I_k)$ where for all $i,j$ (1) $I_i$ is independent in $M_i$ and (2) $I_i \cap I_j = \emptyset$ (since the ground sets of $M_i$ and $M_j$ are disjoint). It seems the strong form of your robustness property follows easily once this confusion is cleared up.

Comment: @AaronDall I did not mean that it is a direct sum of $k$ copies of $M$. Thanks for asking. I did not know that this is not a standard definition, and I will clarify my question accordingly. But the definition is the following:
Let $M$ be a matroid with a ground set $S$. An independent set of $k$-fold sum $M^k$ is a subset $I$ of $S$ where $I$ can be partitioned into $k$ parts such that each part is an independent set of $M$.

Comment: I think, it is usually called 'matroid union', not 'sum', see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Sums_and_unions

Comment: what exactly is your question (or, better to say, two questions): does such a $P$ always exist?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thank you. I agree that the term "matroid union" is more standard. I edited my question accordingly. I also simplified it a bit.